# How could I copy data from a spreadsheet and append it to another AND exlclude header values?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy data from a spreadsheet and append it to another AND exclude header values.

I've tried inputing range values on current range methods but they won't accept strings. I am getting this error message: Cannot find method getDataRange(string). (line 63, file "Code").

Is there a way around this? Should I approach this differently?

```
function copyData(ssA, ssB) {

  //Locates spreadsheets: Source and Destination.
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Leads to Spreadsheet A (source) which is active.
  var ssB = ('spreadsheeturlgoeshere'); //Leads to Spreadsheet B (destination) URL.


  //Source document stuff.
  //Opens source document.
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Opens source sheet.
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  //Gets full range of data.
  var sRange = ss.getDataRange('a2:k');
  //Gets number of rows.
  var sValueLength = ss.getDataRange().getValues().length;
  //Gets A1 notation identifying range of data.
  var A1Range = sRange.getA1Notation();
  //Gets the data values in range.
  var sData = sRange.getValues();

  //Destination document stuff.
  //Opens destination document.
  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssB); 
  //Opens destination sheet.
  var ds = dss.getSheetByName('Output'); 
  //Gets last row from destination sheet.
  var dsLastRow = ds.getLastRow(); 
  var dsLastColumn = ds.getLastColumn(); 

  //Actions.
  //Clears the Google Sheet before copy
  ds.clear({contentsOnly: false});
  //Finds last row on destination sheet and adds source values.
  ds.getRange(dsLastRow+1, 1, sValueLength, dsLastColumn).setValues(sData);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function copyData(ssA, ssB) {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('spreadsheeturlgoeshere');//I would just open by id
  var sh=sss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,11);
  var sData=rg.getValues();
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('Output'); 
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,sData.length,sData[0].length).setValues(sData);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I just added an "h" in the last dsh call. couldn't edit because its supposed to be 6 characters min. Thanks!